# State, Reward per step in a multiagnet environment

Tags: reinforcement-learning

(crossposted:https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/15693/state-reward-per-step-in-a-multiagnet-environment)

In a single agent environment, the agent takes an action, then observes the next state and reward:

```
for ep in num_episodes:
    action = dqn.select_action(state)
    next_state, reward = env.step(action)
```

Implicitly, the for moving the simulation (env) forward is embedded inside the env.step() function.

Now in the multiagent scenario, agent 1 ($a_1$) has to make a decision at time $t_{1a}$, which will finish at time $t_{2a}$, and agent 2 ($a_2$) makes a decision at time $t_{1b} < t_{1a}$  which is finished at $t_{2b} > t_{2a}$.

**If both of their actions would start and finish at the same time**, then it could easily be implemented as:

```
for ep in num_episodes:
    action1, action2 = dqn.select_action([state1, state2])
    next_state_1, reward_1, next_state_2, reward_2 = env.step([action1, action2])
```

because the env can execute both in parallel, wait till they are done, and then return the next states and rewards. But in the scenario that I described previously, it is not clear how to implement this (at least to me). Here, we need to explicitly track time, a check at any timepoint to see if an agent needs to make a decision, Just to be concrete:

```
for ep in num_episodes:
    for t in total_time:
       action1 = dqn.select_action(state1)
       env.step(action1) # this step might take 5t to complete. 
       as such, the step() function won't return the reward till 5 t later. 
        #In the mean time, agent 2 comes and has to make a decision. its reward and next step won't be observed till 10 t later.
```

To summarize, how would one implement a multiagent environment with asynchronous action/rewards per agents?